# How to retrieve Saved Conversation Data in Azure (Tablelogger)

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-table-storage

i was able to saved conversation data using the tablelogger.cs implementation [TableLogger.cs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/TableLogger.cs#L60)

I followed this tutorial to save the conversation history.
[Logging Conversation History](https://chatbotslife.com/managing-state-and-logging-chat-history-in-microsoft-bot-framework-aeb330c688c5)

The code i used to save the chat history was:

```
 var tableName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TableName"].ToString();
 var account = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

 Conversation.UpdateContainer(
            builder =>
            {
                account.CreateCloudTableClient().GetTableReference(tableName).DeleteIfExists();
                builder.RegisterModule(new TableLoggerModule(account, tableName));
            });
```

After checking the Azure table storage explorer I can confirm that information was saved.

[image]

My question is now how to retrieve the conversation data and return it as a string so that I can send it to an agent for review?

Comment: Duplicate of unanswered question from same user: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48313703/how-to-get-chat-history-from-azure-table-storage but this question is more detailed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your conversation messages (let's say messages and not data as Conversation Data is a different thing in Bot Framework vocabulary, it's about state) are stored in an Azure Table, so if you want to get these messages, you just have to query the table.

### Getting the table items

You have several options to query the table, for example

- Microsoft Azure Storage Client Library for .NET: https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/

Sample from the doc to get all rows by partition:

```
// Retrieve the storage account from the connection string.
CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(
    CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("StorageConnectionString"));

// Create the table client.
CloudTableClient tableClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();

// Create the CloudTable object that represents the "people" table.
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("people");

// Construct the query operation for all customer entities where PartitionKey="Smith".
TableQuery<CustomerEntity> query = new TableQuery<CustomerEntity>().Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.Equal, "Smith"));

// Print the fields for each customer.
foreach (CustomerEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}\t{2}\t{3}", entity.PartitionKey, entity.RowKey,
        entity.Email, entity.PhoneNumber);
}
```

Documentation to do a more customized request that will fit your needs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet

- REST API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/querying-tables-and-entities

### Data organization

In your capture you can see that the `PartitionKey` of the table is made of a concatenation of your `channel` and something that looks like a conversation Id. It is confirmed by the sources of `TableLogger` [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/TableLogger.cs#L77):

```
/// <summary>
/// Construct from an IActivity.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="activity"></param>
public ActivityEntity(IActivity activity)
{
    PartitionKey = GeneratePartitionKey(activity.ChannelId, activity.Conversation.Id);
    RowKey = GenerateRowKey(activity.Timestamp.Value);
    From = activity.From.Id;
    Recipient = activity.Recipient.Id;
    Activity = activity;
    Version = 3.0;
}
```

So you will probably be interested in getting all the lines for a given partitionKey.

For the other fields: the `RowKey` is a Timestamp, and `Activity` is mapped to your bot `Activity` object so it's an object which contains several informations. You will have to do some `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Activity>` to get the interesting information.

Comment: sorry, but where can i get the TableQuery<CustomerEntity> ? should i create an internal class? can i simply call the azure table instead?

Comment: It's a sample for the doc as I said. Yes you have to customize to get it working for you, sorry I don't have a running sample exactly matching your need nor the time to do it right now. I added a link to the doc that will guide you to the right method creation that will fit your needs

Comment: And you can use `ActivityEntity` from TableLogger

Comment: Thank you man, you're a savior! thanks for helping me out always! God bless!

Comment: hey man encountered a 409 storageexception error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48395464/tablelogger-cs-throwing-storageexception-409-conflict

Comment: @NicolasR in the sample there is a query  operation for all customer entities with partitionkey 'Smith'. Do you know how  to get all entities (so it does not matter what the value of partitionkey is)?