# How to get conversations data of a azure chat bot using an API or change of source code?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I have integrated a chatbot with Azure chat bot service and linked to a QnA maker service to provide answers. and it is working fine.
Now I want to retrieve all the conversations which are handled by a chatbot. But I didn't find any clues on getting that data.

Can anyone please provide any solution for this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[Write directly to storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) Azure blob transcript storage provides a specialized storage option that allows you to easily save and retrieve user conversations in the form of a recorded transcript. Azure blob transcript storage is particularly useful for automatically capturing user inputs to examine when debugging your bot's performance.
After the TranscriptLoggerMiddleware is added, the Transcript Store will automatically begin to preserve your users' conversations with your bot.

Answer (score 0):

You may refer to the suggestion mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876666/retrieving-chat-bot-conversation-data-in-azure) thread

Within the Bot Framework, the Bot Connector service enables your bot to exchange messages with users on channels that are configured in the Bot Framework Portal and the Bot State service enables your bot to store and retrieve state data that is related to the conversations that your bot conducts using the Bot Connector service. Both services use industry-standard REST and JSON over HTTPS.
See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Additional information: [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48327229/how-to-store-retrieve-bot-data-in-azure-table-storage-with-directline-channel)

Kindly let us know if the above helps or you need further assistance on this issue.