# How to get User credentials in Azure chatbots

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

I have created a baisc QnA Bot using Azure services. But now after deploying the bot. I want it to be able to receive user mail id. So that I can give specific results on basis of the user currently using the bot.

Is it possible?

And what is the correct way of doing so.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the suggestion mentioned in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49876666/retrieving-chat-bot-conversation-data-in-azure) thread.
For details about how to obtain an access token for your bot, see [Authenticate requests from your bot to the Bot Connector service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#bot-to-connector).
Write directly to [storage Azure blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp) transcript storage provides a specialized storage option that allows you to easily save and retrieve user conversations in the form of a recorded transcript.